# Ethernet Card doesn't connect

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

I have tried multiple gigabit network cards, the latest ST1000BT32 Startech, and two different gigabit routers. The machine refuse to connect and pull an IP address. I've tried different ethernet cords, different routers, different ethernet cards. I've even tried a Startech 10/100 ST100S... it just lights up and never makes a connection... just says connecting and dies. Then retries. I have also tried it on different Ubuntu installs... nothing works.

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ifconfig

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr bc:5f:f4:57:8e:13
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth2 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:0a:cd:22:88:27
inet6 addr: fe80::20a:cdff:fe22:8827/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:5528 (5.5 KB)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:90 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:90 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:8661 (8.6 KB) TX bytes:8661 (8.6 KB)
```

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to setup dhcp using the /etc/network/interfaces file instead of network manager.

Your /etc/network/interfaces file needs to look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If eth0 is the interface you want to connect on.  I am assuming whatever router you have connected to is setup as a DHCP server.

The following is an example configuration for a static ip:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.90
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: I tried this. When I do, during the boot up it says something like waiting for network configuration, then boots without network configuration. I tried this for both eth0 and eth2.

Comment: Is your router set up as a DHCP server?

Comment: Yep. I even tried a switch... same result. Never connects.

Comment: Have you tried putting your box on the same subnet as your router by giving it a static ip?

Comment: I haven't tried a static IP yet. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I added the static IP config above.